# Univariant analysis in survival study

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, medicine, logrank-test

I don't know a lot about statistics and survival analysis so this might be a dull question.

I'm performing a survival analysis where I want to study the possible risk or protective factors that could lead to the incidence of a proctological pathology after the surgery of another proctological patology. I would like to obtain the Kaplan Meier curves and compare them using the logrank test. My question is if I can obtain a univariant HZ with the logrank test (since I've been reading that de Cox regression analysis is multivariant). After that,I would like to introduce to a multivariant analysis the variables that are statistally significative in the univariant analysis. In this case, should I use Cox?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do log-rank tests comparing Kaplan-Meier curves. For categorical predictors the score test of a Cox regression is equivalent to the log-rank test. For continuous predictors you would need to categorize the values, which is generally a [bad idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230750/28500); a Cox model can handle continuous predictors readily and model them flexibly as with regression splines.

> I would like to introduce to a multivariant analysis the variables that are statistally significative in the univariant analysis.

I interpret "mutltivariant" and "univariate" here to mean "multiple-predictor" and "single-predictor" regressions. What you propose, although often done, isn't good practice. Whenever you use the outcomes to choose predictors of a model you risk optimistic overfitting; your model might fit your current data sample but won't extend well to new data samples.

There are principled ways to proceed. Frank Harrell's online [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) describes general aspects of regression modeling (Chapter 2), strategies for developing multiple-predictor models without peeking at the outcomes (Chapter 4), and specific issues in survival analysis (Chapters 17-21).