# When is good to bin variables in regression setting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, continuous-data, discrete-data, linear

As discussed [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/dividingcontinuousintocategories.html), In most cases, bin a continuous variable to discrete one is a bad idea. But when it will be good?

May attempt to answer:

- Can I think binning will increase the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) of the model? As suggested in this post?  [Should we bin continuous variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153400/should-we-bin-continuous-variables)
- If a variable has some extreme outliers or lots noise (say, income, there are persons make billions, and some data points are incorrect collected and shown as 0), binning might be better?

Comment: *none linear* relationships? :)

Comment: See [What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/17230). A brief riposte to your 2nd point is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable/68839#comment228826_117994

Comment: Didn't you ask this before: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230750/when-should-we-discretize-binning-continuous-independent-variables-features-an/230783#230783 ?

Comment: @MatthewDrury wow, it is surprising I do not remember my own questions. Worked overtime too much recently.

Comment: Heh.  Occasionally I find an answer and think "What, that's so wrong!" and then I scroll down, and it's me from a year ago.

Comment: @MatthewDrury but this question is good that Scortchi provided some links I did not found. Also, It remains me to study your answer and code carefully and make notes !

Comment: Eep.  That code is, not so good.

Comment: Binning, taken to an extreme, puts all data into a single category--which obviously has no variance.  Therefore binning *decreases* variance; it does not increase it. However, if you are referring to the variance of the *error* in a regression model, then binning a regressor (assuming the bins continue to be treated numerically rather than as factors) typically will *increase* the error variance because it destroys the (presumed) linear relationship between regressor and response, introducing "noise."